# How to force ReactNative ListView to update a row when row-data change?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

ReactNative's ListView is little bit odd when it comes to data updates.

I have an array of objects (name: Item), that have 3 properties:

- id (int)
- name (string)
- enabled (bool)

The array of items is displayed in a ListView. Each row shows the name of the item and a checkmark representing the enabled-state (red on true, gray on false). In my example it is simplified to a simple string "true"/"false".

Each row is embedded in a TouchableOpacity with a onPress-EventHandler, that toggles the enabled-state of the represented item.

Unfortunately, the ListView won't update the row.

While debugging the rowHasChanged-Event, it turns out that the rowHasChanged-Event could never determine the changed state because both rows already get the new state after toggling the enabled-property without any update to the UI.

## Here is my Code:

### The Item-Class: Item.js

```
export default class Item {

  constructor(id, name, enabled) {
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._enabled = enabled;
  }

  get id() {return this._id}

  get name() {return this._name}
  set name(value) {this._name = value}

  get enabled() {return this._enabled}
  set enabled(value) {this._enabled = value}
  
}
```

### The ListView:

```
'use strict';

import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';

import {View,TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight,
  Text, ListView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import Item from './Item';

class ItemListView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.updateListView = this.updateListView.bind(this);
    this.toggleItemEnabled = this.toggleItemEnabled.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 != row2
            }),
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateListView(this.props.items)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.updateListView(nextProps.items)
    }

  updateListView(items) {
    this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(
                items.slice() // copy items to a new array
            ),
        });
  }

  toggleItemEnabled(item) {
    item.enabled = !item.enabled;

    this.updateListView(this.props.items);
  }

  renderItem(item) {
    console.log('Render', item.enabled, item.name)
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}} onPress={ () => this.toggleItemEnabled(item) }>
        <View style={s.row}>
              <Text>{item.name + ' ' + item.enabled}</Text>
          </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={s.container}>
        <ListView
          style={s.listView}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

}

ItemListView.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.array
};

ItemListView.defaultProps = {
  items: [],
};

export default ItemListView;


const s = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  },

  row: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 12,
    paddingBottom: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'gray',
  },

  innerContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

});
```

How to fix this behaviour, that the ListView gets updated when row-data changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is the `ListView` data source is not getting updated when you update `item`. The `item` passed to `toggleItemEnabled` belongs to `state.datasource` whereas you are setting the datasource for `props.items`

**Solution 1**

Clone the rows and set the rows again

```
toggleItemEnabled(item, sectionId, rowId) {
    newItems = this.props.items.slice();
    newItems[rowId].enabled = !newItems[rowId].enabled;

    this.updateListView(newItems);
}
```

**Solution 2**

This is the way I would prefer. I generally create a separate component for `Row`
So you should refactor as follows

Create a new `Row.js`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       enabled: false;
    };
 }


toggleItemEnabled() {
    this.setState({enabled: !this.state.enabled});

}

render() {
 item = this.props.data;
 return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1}} onPress={ () => this.toggleItemEnabled() }>
        <View style={s.row}>
              <Text>{item.name + ' ' + this.state.enabled}</Text>
          </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )

}
```

Then in your main component in render row method call this Row component

```
renderItem(item) {
     return(
         <Row data={item} />
     );
 }
```

Comment: You beautiful, beautiful person! This helped me no end, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
toggleItem(item){
    item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
    const items = [...this.state.dataSource];
    const index = items.findIndex((x) => x.id === item.id);
    items[index] = item;
    this.setState({ dataSource: items });
}
```